# re-requesting xml data after updating variables in Flash

Tags: mysql, xml, actionscript-3, flash

Having a few problems that after three days of googling and coding I am unable to find any suitable answers so, I'm hoping that someone with far more Flash AS3 knowledge than me can help. I have frame on the Maintimeline of a flash Movie which requests and loads PHP generated XML. The PHP file is passed three variables from Flash which are then used to populate certain parts of the MySQL query in the PHP file. It all works wonderfully and I can populate a myriad dynamic text fields via my loadXML function. here's my code:

```
var req:URLRequest=new URLRequest("http://example.com/returnusers.php");
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();      
phpVars.Group = myVar1;
phpVars.Company = myVar2;
phpVars.startRow = myStartRow;
req.data = phpVars;
var xml:XMLList;    
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);
xmlLoader.load(req);
```

My problem is that I also have several buttons that, when clicked, will change the values of the myVar1, myVar2 and myStartRow. and thus change the parameters of the query in the PHP file. I would like to resend these to the same PHP file for an updated xml output and for my dynamic text fields to be updated with the new xml data.The only problem is is that I don't know how. As you can problably tell I'm no Tech Wizz but I'd really appreciate if someone out there could help... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to implement is a classic MVC design - in simple words you have a model (database + php) that is dynamic (changes during run time) and you want your view to change according to the changes made in the model (the view is binded to the model)

The solution requires some architectural work that is a bit advanced and will take some learning time , this is a good start :  http://www.moock.org/lectures/mvc/

Comment: Thanks so much for such a quick reply. I've looked at some of colin moock's earlier stuff  quite a few years back in FlashMX days which really good. Unfortunately whilst your answer and Colins model makes perfect sense it is, gulp, way beyond my level of coding expertise.I thought I was just being dumb and missing something when I couldn't work it out. There must be an easy way I thought, to change the variables and resend the same request back to the PHP page.